# Showing different links depending on who is logged in

Tags: html, session, if-statement, navigation

I'm trying to create a few links that change depending on who is logged in, for example when a user logs in, log in changes to log out, just started making the if statements but they dont seem to recognise the sessions. Can anyone see an issue? Excuse the poor layout, been playing around.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skeleton.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css" />
  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment1</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->

  <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))
      {


      ?>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="row">

      <center><h4>Basic Requirements</h4>
        <pre>        
      <a href="loginform.php" title="back to home">Logout</a>                     <a href="registrationform.php" title="back to home">Registration</a>                     <a href="contactus.php" title="back to home">Contact</a>                     <a href="searchform.php" title="back to home">Search</a>
        </pre>
    </div>
    </center>
  </div>
  <?php
      }
      else if (isset($_SESSION['adminlogged']))
      {

      }
      else
      {


  ?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <center><h4>Basic Requirements</h4>
        <pre>        
      <a href="loginform.php" title="back to home">Logout</a>                     <a href="registrationform.php" title="back to home">Registration</a>                     <a href="contactus.php" title="back to home">Contact</a>                     <a href="searchform.php" title="back to home">Search</a>
        </pre>
    </div>
    </center>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Loginsubmit.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'connection.php';
include 'loginform.php';

?>
<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    //Counts up how many matches there are in the database
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM users WHERE Username ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "'AND Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    /*$queryadmin = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM admin WHERE Username ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "'AND Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";*/
    /*$resultadmin = mysqli_query($connection, $queryadmin);*/
    /*$rowadmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadmin);*/
    //If count is more than 0, log user in.
    if ($row["cnt"] > 0) 
    {
        $_SESSION["userlogged"] =  $user;
        echo "Logged in - Press the home button to return to the homepage";

    } 

    else if ($rowadmin["cnt"] > 0 )
        {
            $_SESSION["adminlogged"] = $user;
            echo "Logged in - Press the home button to return to the homepage";
        }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Not a valid login';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your index page needs the session_start(); to read session variables

```
            session_start();
            echo $_SESSION['userlogged'];
```

Comment: added that in, same problem still unfortunately

Comment: try to check the value of $_SESSION['userlogged'] on the index page

Comment: Sorry how can i do that? fairly new to this

Comment: Tried it, doesn't echo anything just shows all the HTML and it's ignoring the if statement

Comment: when you login, do you see this message 'Logged in - Press the home button to return to the homepage'?

Comment: Yes mate, and there's where I assign the session to userlogged

Comment: Sorry just seen it echoes the logged in name :)

Comment: Try replacing if (isset($_SESSION['userlogged'])) with if ($_SESSION['userlogged'])

Comment: Still the same issue I'm afraid!